# How to set cells for table view with sections

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have a dynamic table view, that in fact is like static but I have set it dynamic because is embedded in a view controller. I have the issue that table view has 4 sections of 3 cells set in the table view delegate methods, but I have an array with dictionaries ready to fill cells data.

As you can see in this code, it is always setting the same data in all sections because indexPath.row is used to iterate through the array, and it doesn't go up to three, despite the  array has more values.

Here is the current code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 NSDictionary *jornada = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: [copaReyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        self.copaReytable.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


        if (indexPath.row==0){

            cuartosReyCell *headerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"header"];

            if (headerCell == nil) {
                headerCell = [[ cuartosReyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:@"header"];

            }

            headerCell.cuartos.text = @"1/4 final";

            headerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.008 green:0.235 blue:0.451 alpha:1];

            return headerCell;
        }

        if (indexPath.row==1){

            localCopaReyCell *localCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"local"];

            if (localCell == nil) {
                localCell = [[ localCopaReyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:@"local"];

            }


            NSString *equipoLoc = [jornada valueForKey:@"id_local"];

            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",[self applicationDocumentsDirectory],equipoLoc ]];

            [localCell.escudo setImage:img];

            localCell.escudo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

            localCell.equiLoc.text = [equiposDic valueForKey:equipoLoc]; 

            localCell.equiLoc.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.004 green:0.29 blue:0.553 alpha:1];

            localCell.primerPartido.text = [jornada valueForKey:@"res_local"]; 

            localCell.primerPartido.textColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0.722 green:0.145 blue:0.345 alpha:1];

            return localCell;
        }

        if (indexPath.row==2){

            visitanteCopaReyCell *visitanteCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"visitante"];

            if (visitanteCell == nil) {
                visitanteCell = [[ visitanteCopaReyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:@"visitante"];

            }

            NSString *equipoLoc = [jornada valueForKey:@"id_local"];

            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",[self applicationDocumentsDirectory],equipoLoc ]];

            [visitanteCell.escudo setImage:img];

            visitanteCell.escudo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

            visitanteCell.equiLoc.text = [equiposDic valueForKey:equipoLoc]; 

            visitanteCell.equiLoc.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.004 green:0.29 blue:0.553 alpha:1];

            visitanteCell.primerPartido.text = [jornada valueForKey:@"res_local"]; 

            visitanteCell.primerPartido.textColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0.004 green:0.29 blue:0.553 alpha:1];

            return visitanteCell;

        }
```

I don't know how to iterate correctly over copaReyArray and set sections and rows. The array contains 8 dictionaries that correspond to every section (8 sections of 3 cells).

many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop over an array, my preferred method is a `forin`:

```
for(Object *obj in array) {
    // do stuff with obj
}
```

Keep in mind though that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the table view data source is already inside a loop (one that's buried somewhere out of view). You can use the `indexPath` parameter to determine where you are. It contains `section` and `row` properties.